# unable to read a string inside a loop structure using fgets() function

Tags: c, string, fgets, gets

I used `fgets()` and `gets()` also for getting a string as input inside a loop. In the first execution, it worked properly but in the second time, it skips the inputting step and straight away goes to the next line.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct student
{
    int roll,m[3];
    float avg;
    char name[30];
}s[5];
void main()
{
    int i;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter thr student details:");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("\nstudent[%d] name:",i+1);
        fgets(s[i].name,30,stdin);
        printf("student[%d] register number:  ",i+1);
        scanf("%d",&s[i].roll);
        printf("student[%d] marks:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d%d%d",&s[i].m[0],&s[i].m[1],&s[i].m[2]);
        s[i].avg=(s[i].m[0]+s[i].m[1]+s[i].m[2])/3;
    }
    printf("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n  NAME        REG.NO      AVERAGE");
    printf("\n-----------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n      DISTINCTION");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(s[i].avg>74)
            printf("\n%-20s%-10d%.2f",s[i].name,s[i].roll,s[i].avg);
    printf("\n              FIRST CLASS");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if((s[i].avg<74)&&s[i].avg>50)
            printf("\n%-20s%-10d%.2f",s[i].name,s[i].roll,s[i].avg);
    printf("\n                 FAIL");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        if(s[i].avg<50)
            printf("\n%-20s%-10d%.2f",s[i].name,s[i].roll,s[i].avg);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code.

Comment: Also the data you are reading from.

Comment: @datashaman i actually want 2 add 5 details... but ly t first detail gets scanned

Comment: If you use the same method of input for all cases, you will reduce the chance of bugs. Use fgets for all inputs, and then sscanf afterwards for parsing the input. Don't use scanf directly from stdin like this. You are mixing two different methods of input, which will also confuse the user.

Comment: `s[i].avg=(s[i].m[0]+s[i].m[1]+s[i].m[2])/3;` --> `s[i].avg=(s[i].m[0]+s[i].m[1]+s[i].m[2])/3.0;`

Comment: `"%d%d%d"` --> `"%d%d%d%*c"` or etc...

Comment: First scanf-not-consuming-newline question of the day! Now I just need a float != float  for a Stackoverflow bingo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as told by @chux , `scanf` leaves '\n' in the `stdin` ( memory buffer ) , and `fgets()` takes value until there is a '\n' in the buffer , in order to clear the buffer the statement `fflush(stdin);` is used before the `fgets()` statement

Answer (score 0):

```
Enter thr student details:
student[1] name:abcd <Enter>
```

`fgets` reads until the size limit is reached or `EOF` is returned or a new line (`\n`) character is encountered. In the above scenario, it reads `abcd` and also reads `\n`,and returns.

```
student[1] register number:  12<Enter>
student[1] marks:
12 13 14<Enter>
```

Now, you are using `scanf` to read the numbers. `scanf` with `%d` returns until a number is encountered or `EOF` is seen. It ignores all the new line characters.

After the above two steps you are left with an extra `\n` in the input stream.(since `scanf` doesn't actually read it).

Now when you have a next call for `fgets`, there is already a `\n` first. It returns there, without actually prompting for the next name.

Solution:

Put a `getch()`, after reading the marks. This removes the leading `\n` from the stream.
Or, read the name using `scanf` itself.

```
scanf("%s", s[i].name);
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%d%d%d")` leaves the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or `'\n'` in `stdin`.  The following `fgets()` then reads only `"\n"`.

The best solution is to use the `fgets()/sscanf()` combination.  Robust code checks the return results.

```
{
  char buf[100];
  printf("\nstudent[%d] name:",i+1);
  if (fgets(s[i].name, sizeof s[i].name, stdin) == NULL) 
    Handle_EOF();
  printf("student[%d] register number:  ", i+1);
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) 
    Handle_EOF();
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d", &s[i].roll) != 1) 
    Handle_InputError();
  printf("student[%d] marks:\n",i+1);
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) 
    Handle_EOF();
  if (sscanf(buf, "%d%d%d", &s[i].m[0], &s[i].m[1], &s[i].m[2]) != 3)
    Handle_InputError();
  s[i].avg = (s[i].m[0] + s[i].m[1] + s[i].m[2])/3;
}
```